# Getting inappropriate rank while merging and arranging 2 list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Below is my models:

```
public class Test
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public List<VariantsRank> VariantsRanks { get; set; }
}

public class VariantsRank
{
    public int VariantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

I have an existing `Test` instance which contains the following values for `VariantsRanks`

```
VariantId = 10, Name = "V1", Rank = 0
VariantId = 11, Name = "V2", Rank = 1
```

I then need to merge the following `VariantsRank`

```
VariantId = 12, Name = "V3", Rank = 0
VariantId = 13, Name = "V4", Rank = 1
```

and increment the `Rank` to produce the following output

```
VariantId = 10, Name = "V1", Rank = 0
VariantId = 11, Name = "V2", Rank = 1
VariantId = 12, Name = "V3", Rank = 2
VariantId = 13, Name = "V4", Rank = 3
```

and I use the following code which works correctly (`List1` is the original list, and `List2` is the list to be merged)

```
int highestOrder = (List1.VariantsRanks.Max(cpo => cpo.Rank)) + 1;
foreach (var rank in List2.VariantsRanks)
{
    var match = List1.VariantsRanks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VariantId == rank.VariantId);
    if (match != null) // found
    {
        match.Rank = rank.Rank;
    }
    else
    {
        rank.Rank = highestOrder;
        highestOrder = highestOrder + 1;
        List1.VariantsRanks.Add(rank);
    }
}
```

I then need to merge the following `VariantsRank` to the new list (note the matching `VariantId` values, but they are in reverse order)

```
VariantId = 13, Name = "V4", Rank = 0
VariantId = 12, Name = "V3", Rank = 1
```

so that the output should be

```
VariantId = 10, Name = "V1", Rank = 0
VariantId = 11, Name = "V2", Rank = 1
VariantId = 13, Name = "V4", Rank = 2
VariantId = 12, Name = "V3", Rank = 3
```

however the above code instead outputs

```
VariantId = 10, Name = "V1", Rank = 0
VariantId = 11, Name = "V2", Rank = 1
VariantId = 12, Name = "V3", Rank = 1
VariantId = 13, Name = "V4", Rank = 0
```

and the `Rank` values are not incremented correctly

How do I modify the code to ensure that duplicate `VariantId` are not added, but increment the `Rank`?

Comment: You code needs to be in the question, not a link to a fiddle

Comment: @StephenMuecke :Actually that would increase length of my question and reason for giving the fiddle as it would be easy for you to directly see the output and directly work with the code as pointed out by Enigmativity before.Long question doesnt get attention

Comment: Cut your existing code down to 2 items per list and show the code where you manipulate the list - that is what is important (and the fiddle is not even working - its timing out)

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Yes actually there is some problem with that site because it wasnt working when i ran it for the first time.After 5- 10 minutes i was able to run it.You want me to post code here with 2 items?

Comment: Probably no need. You code does exactly what it should and does work - except that you have commented out the line `List2.Clear()` so you adding 8 items to `List2` - i.e. with duplicates so your hitting the `match.Rank = rank.Rank;` line of code for items 5 - 8 :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136320/discussion-between-learning-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

You issue is that in the 2 merge, your adding items with values that match the `VariantId` in the existing list. This means that you hit the code in the `if` block, which resets the values of the existing items to the value of the `Rank` in the model your posting.

For example, in the first iteration of your loop, `match` is the existing item with `VariantID = 13` and your set its `Rank` to equal the value of `rank.Rank` which is `0`.

You need to first remove any matches from your existing list, and then iterate through the posted values, update their `Rank` and add to the collection.

You code should be

```
// Get the VariantId values of the list to be merged
var ids = List2.VariantsRanks.Select(x => x.VariantId);
// Remove any matches from the existing list
List1.VariantsRanks.RemoveAll(x => ids.Contains(x.VariantId));
// Calculate the current highest rank
int highestOrder = (List1.VariantsRanks.Max(x => x.Rank));
foreach (var rank in List2.VariantsRanks)
{
    // Update the rank
    rank.Rank = ++highestOrder; // pre-increment
    // Add to the existing list
    List1.VariantsRanks.Add(rank);
}
```

---

Based on comments in chat that the the second list might contain items that need to be inserted in the middle of the first list, then the code would need to be

```
// Get the VariantId's of the first and last items in the list to be merged
var firstID = List2.VariantsRanks.First().VariantId;
var lastID = List2.VariantsRanks.Last().VariantId;
// Get the indexers of those items in the original list
var firstIndex = List1.VariantsRanks.FindIndex(x => x.VariantId == firstID);
var lastIndex = List1.VariantsRanks.FindIndex(x => x.VariantId == lastID);
if (firstIndex > lastIndex) // in case they are in descending order
{
    var temp = lastIndex;
    lastIndex = firstIndex;
    firstIndex = temp;
}
// Remove matches from the original list
for (int i = firstIndex; i < lastIndex + 1; i++)
{
    List1.VariantsRanks.RemoveAt(firstIndex);
}
// Inset the items from the list to be merged
for(int i = 0; i < List2.VariantsRanks.Count; i++)
{
    List1.VariantsRanks.Insert(firstIndex + i, List2.VariantsRanks[i]);
}
/ Re-number the Rank
for(int i = 0; i < List1.VariantsRanks.Count; i++)
{
    List1.VariantsRanks[i].Rank = i;
}
```

Note, the above will only work if the values of `VariantId` in the merged list are consecutive (in either ascending or descending order)